# Kubernetes v1.25.11, resource not found for name: "abc" namespace: "staging" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I recently upgraded kubernetes version to 1.25.11 and updated the api versions as the deprecated API migration doc (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/).
The upgrade was successfully.
Now I am try to deploy the recently developed features of my app, In CICD pipeline get below error

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: [resource mapping not found for name: "abc-cron" namespace: "staging" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"
```

As for above shared doc I updated the version from batch/v1beta1 to batch/v1

yaml:

```yaml
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
metadata:
  name: abc-cron
  namespace: staging
  uid: ca924a0c-4696-401e-9224-9e92039aa089
  resourceVersion: '79995787'
  generation: 2
  creationTimestamp: '2023-01-12T13:54:31Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: app-staging
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: staging
  managedFields:
    - manager: helm
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2023-01-12T13:54:31Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
        f:spec:
          f:concurrencyPolicy: {}
          f:failedJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:jobTemplate:
            f:spec:
              f:backoffLimit: {}
              f:template:
                f:spec:
                  f:containers:
                    k:{"name":"abc-cron"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:env:
                        .: {}
                        k:{"name":"ENVIRONMENT"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:value: {}
                      f:image: {}
                      f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:resources: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                  f:dnsPolicy: {}
                  f:imagePullSecrets:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"docker-secret"}: {}
                  f:restartPolicy: {}
                  f:schedulerName: {}
                  f:securityContext: {}
                  f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
          f:schedule: {}
          f:successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {}
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2023-01-12T13:57:21Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:suspend: {}
spec:
  schedule: 0 9 1,16 * *
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  suspend: true
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 4
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: abc-cron
              image: msapp.azurecr.io/abccron:ms-staging
              env:
                - name: ENVIRONMENT
                  value: ms-staging
              resources: {}
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: Never
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          securityContext: {}
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: docker-secret
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
status: {}
```

I am new to Kubernetes and was not able to resolve the issue. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly share the error its giving after updating the version to "batch/v1" in the manifest files.

Comment: Can you share the yaml of your cronjob, chances are that you can just adjust the api in there and be good.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal, I am getting Error: UPGRADE FAILED: [resource mapping not found for name: "abc-cron" namespace: "staging" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"

Comment: @RickRackow, I shared the yaml of cornjob. please check

Comment: you can check the exact version of cronjob by running "kubectl api-resources | grep -i cronjob"

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal, by executing the cmd I can see the api-version as batch/v1. But still in CD pipeline while deploying getting the same above shared error          kubectl api-resources | grep -i cronjob
cronjobs                          cj                  batch/v1                               true         CronJob

Comment: There is no problem with cronjob manifest file which has been provided.  this getting created / applied in lower version of k8s 1.21.x and 1.27.x versions as well. more investigation required from cicd pipeline perspective.